# Map Overview in QGIS not working?

Tags: qgis, map-overviews

I am trying to create a map overview of a zoomed in area in Zambia. I am doing this step by step from a very nice tutorial, however, in the 'Map Frame' dropdown list there is nothing to select (See pic)[image: Map overview creation]

Comment: I managed to re-create this issue, and I managed to fix it, but I'm not sure exactly what fixed it. My best guess is that the overview map must be created AFTER the close-up map.

Comment: Thanks! Your guess was correct. Actually I also noticed that it worked the other way around but it never crossed my mind to recreate them the other way around. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in 2.18.10-12. it's fixed in the (as of time of writing this answer upcoming) .13 release.